# Python Type Hinting: Subclass not compatible with generic

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, types, type-hinting

I have the following simple classes

```py
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass
```

I want another class, `C`, with a method which will accept as an argument any subclass of `A`, which will default to `B`. I thought a `Generic` would be a suitable candidate here:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)


class C(Generic[T]):
    def foo(self, assistant: type[T] = B) -> None:
        pass
```

However, when I run mypy I get the error

> Incompatible default for argument "assistant" (default has type "type[B]", argument has type "type[T]"

I find this a little confusing, as I thought the idea of `TypeVar('T', bound=A)` was to create a type compatible with any subclass of `A` (so in particular `B`).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Instances of a subclass are also instances of the parent class. But the subclass itself is not an instance of the type of the parent class.

Comment: @Barmar that's true, so it's inherently the use of `type` in `type[T] = B` (alongside the fact I need to pass in a class, rather than an instance) which is causing the issue

Comment: @Barmar statically speaking, [I don't think that's true](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=8b2ebd338c121cbf56ddd08a44fbcffb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need generics. You should just do

```
class C:
    def foo(self, assistant: type[A] = B) -> None:
        ...
```

`type[A]` is already the type representing all classes that descend from `A` (including `A`).

What you've done is create a generic class. That class takes type parameters, like `c: C[B] = C()`, and the argument to `foo` must be a descendant of whatever the type parameter was.

With your class definition, if you did

```
class D(A): pass

c: C[D] = C()
```

then `c.foo` would require a descendant of `D` as an argument. However, the default value `B` is not a descendant of `D`, so the default value would be an invalid argument, hence the error message.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. The example also helps clarify the rationale behind the error message. I think my fundamental oversight was naively think that the behaviour of TypeVar/generics would lift from the instance to the type, which clearly wouldn't make sense. "type[A] is already the type representing all classes that descend from A (including A)." is the takeaway here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you could define something like `C[D]` if `D` inherits from `A`. But in this case `type[B]` is not a subtype of `type[D]` (which would be the type of the argument) and therefore mypy's complains are absolutely correct.

Comment: Definitely, very good point